# Cutting a multidimensional numpy array in half alongside a selected axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array like this:

```
[
  [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7,8,9,10],
    [11,12,13,14,15]
  ],
  [
    [16,17,18,19,20],
    [21,22,23,24,25],
    [26,27,28,29,30]
  ]
]
```

and would like to create a function that cuts it in half alongside a specified axis, without including the middle element in case the size is uneven. So if I say `my_function(my_ndarray, 0)`, I want to get

```
[
  [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7,8,9,10],
    [11,12,13,14,15]
  ]
]
```

for `my_function(my_ndarray, 1)` I want to get

```
[
  [
    [1,2,3,4,5]
  ],
  [
    [16,17,18,19,20]
  ]
]
```

and for `my_function(my_ndarray, 2)` I want to get

```
[
  [
    [1,2],
    [6,7],
    [11,12]
  ],
  [
    [16,17],
    [21,22],
    [26,27]
  ]
]
```

My first attempt involved the [np.split()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) method, but it unfortunately runs into problems when the length of the axis is an uneven number and doesn't allow me to specify that I would like to omit. In theory I could make an if statement and cut away the last slice of the selected axis if this is the case, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: How is that cutting it in half? The only thing you're doing is indexing at `0` on a specified axis, so `a[0]`, `a[:,0]` and `a[:,:,0]`

Comment: Half of `[1,2,3]` while omitting the middle element is `[1]`. If the array was `[1,2,3,4,5]` then the desired result would be `[1,2]`

Comment: Is that a matrix, or rather a 2x3x5 array?

Comment: @yatu I realized that the example I supplied was misleading, I adjusted it accordingly. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @9769953 it's a ndarray, I adjusted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an axis `axis` and an array `a`, I think you can can do

```
def my_function(a, axis):
    l = a.shape[axis]//2
    return a.take(range(l), axis=axis)
```

Examples:

```
>>> my_function(a, 0)
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]])

>>> my_function(a, 1)
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]])

>>> my_function(a, 2)
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 6,  7],
        [11, 12]],

       [[16, 17],
        [21, 22],
        [26, 27]]])
```

Comment: elegant answer!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
def slice_n(a, n):
    slices = [slice(None)]*a.ndim
    slices[n] = slice(0, a.shape[n]//2)
    return a[tuple(slices)]

slice_n(a, 0)
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]])

slice_n(a, 1)
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]])

slice_n(a, 2)
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 6,  7],
        [11, 12]],

       [[16, 17],
        [21, 22],
        [26, 27]]])
```

used input (`a`):

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
        [26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]])
```